# Help with unclogging the kitchen sink using a plunger

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink, clog

I tried to unclog my kitchen sink using a plunger, but it's not work, probably because the dishwasher is draining to the same pipe; see the Y-connector in the photo below.

[image]

I want to cap off the connection where the black hose is connecting to, but I don't know the size.

By the way, the nuts at the P-trap were tightened when I was using the plunger.  I also using a 1/4" 25-foot-long plumbing snake to try to clear the clog but had no luck.

Comment: If your 25' snake didn't clear it, a plunger isn't going to either.  A plunger can get flow going when the problem is in the trap,  if it's much further down the line you won't be able to get the needed compression with a plunger.

Comment: I was hoping plunging will work up to 25 feet and beyond once I cap the dishwasher connection, because water is practically an incompressible fluid =)

Comment: Get one of these: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0000CBIWC/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?qid=1462808514&sr=8-1&pi=SY200_QL40&keywords=drain+king&dpPl=1&dpID=31vUSYDWqcL&ref=plSrch and attach it to the garden hose.  It expands.  Take the pipe apart and insert after the trap.  Have a helper turn the water on so you can hold the drain king in the pipe until it expands.  Warning tho: if you have crappy corroded pipe or weak joints you may blow a hole open.

Comment: The plunger only works on the trap arm.  Once the drain runs into a vent, the plunger is no good.

Comment: @Tyson Won't that device have the problem Tester101 cites? The vent will prevent using pressure to blow the clog out.

Comment: Did you try sodium hydroxide (commonly sold as red devil lye or drain-o)?

Comment: Update -- I hired Roto-Rooter, who cleared the clog for me.  It was located down a cast-iron pipe but before they join together to leave the house.  I guess my 1/4" snake was too flimsy to take out the clog.  With hindsight, I would use the plunger after I disconnect the black dishwasher connection and plug it with a rag.